# Excel columns data Need to be converted into list of values enclosed in double quotes and then write to json file by excluding starting brackets

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

Below is the excel file

```
col1 col2

1     a,b,c
2     a
```

I am reading excel file data into dataframe

```
df=pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheetname='data')
```

df

```
   col1   col2
0     1   a,b,c
0     2   a

dfj=df.to_json(orient="records")
```

dfj

```
'[{"col1":1,"col2":"a,b,c"}]'
```

Here i need dfj output to be like this

```
'{"col1":1,"col2":["a","b","c"]}'
```

Can someone help me to code this.

Comment: @ Codelt AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I have posted my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57213213/3091398).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df["col2"] = df["col2"].str.split(",")
dfj = df.to_json(orient="records")
print (dfj)
[{"col1":1,"col2":["a","b","c"]}]
```

If possible multiple columns filled by strings and need split them:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(","))
dfj = df.to_json(orient="records")
```

Or create list of columns for spliting:

```
cols = ['col2', 'another col', ...]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(","))
dfj = df.to_json(orient="records")
```

If need remove first and last `[]` use `strip` - `.str` is not necessary, because use pure python:

```
dfj = df.to_json(orient="records").strip('[]')
print (dfj)
{"col1":1,"col2":["a","b","c"]}
```

Comment: df.to_json(orient="records")
Out[44]: '[{"col1":1,"col2":["a","b","c"]}]'

Comment: here in the starting i am getting '[ , this should be replaced with '

Comment: @DppriyaReddy - like `dfj = df.to_json(orient="records").strip('[]')` ?

Comment: Thats great its working. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# json string
dfjs = '[{"col1":1,"col2":"a,b,c"}]'

# converting json string into json object 
dfj = json.loads(dfjs)[0]

# converting col2 values into list of values 
dfj["col2"] = dfj["col2"].split(",")

# converting json object into dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(dfj)

print(df)
```

*Output*:

```
  col1 col2
0     1    a
1     1    b
2     1    c
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/DangerousSphericalCamel).